# Moving image dynamically when user resizes window

Tags: c#, image, winforms, resize

I'm going to be short and sweet with only needed information. I'm making an application which has multiple forms displayed in a MDI parent.

I want my users to be able to resize this window and the things i place inside each form resize and move when they resize the window. I do not know how to do this. When i anchor the picture box containing my image to the sides of the form i'm assuming it would work but when you run the application you are not resizing the form, you are resizing the MDIparent form which does not affect the image.
Help.

Edit: removed  useless code.

MDIparent code:

```
        private void ribbonButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (Form f in this.MdiChildren)
            {
                if (f.GetType() == typeof(Form2))
                {
                    f.Activate();
                    return;
                }
            }
            Form form2 = new Form2();
            form2.MdiParent = this;
            form2.Show();
        }
```

Form2 that is the MDICHILD:

```
        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnLoad(e);
            this.ControlBox = false;
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            this.BringToFront();
        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

Comment: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: i created a more minimal post :)

Answer (score 0):

When the MDI parent is resized, the child form sizes of the MDI will not be affected. You will need to do this manually. So, anchoring is the right solution to the child form. Then you will need to set the sizes of the children manually on the resize event of the parent, according to the parent's size. This is all I can say because your post is not clear. Maybe some screenshots could help.